# Attempting to append/remove child; nodeFailed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a label upon hovering over an icon and the label disappears when no longer hovering over it. Upon hovering over it the first time, the label is created and removed with no problem; that is the expected result.

When the cursor hovers over the icon multiple times, the label successfully renders. However when the cursor is no longer hovering I get this error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

I'm looking to understand what is causing this error. I figure it may have something with having the nested event handler, and if it does I'm not sure why.

HTML

```
<div id="main-icon-links">
    <div class="icon_wrapper">
        <svg id="post-alerts" width="20" height="12.5" stroke-width="2" stroke="black">
            <rect fill="ghostwhite" width="20" height="12.5"/>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="6.25" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />
            <line x1="10" y1="6.25" x2="20" y2="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
let posts = document.getElementById("post-alerts");
posts.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = "Inbox";
  this.parentElement.appendChild(p);
  this.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(p); <<< DOM exception occurs here
  })
})
```

Comment: Try `p.remove()`. Simpler to write and an element has it's own remove method

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it's because of the nested event listeners. You add a new moseout Listener every time your mouseover listener fires. But you never delete the old mouseout listener. This one tries to remove the first added p, which is already gone. This causes the dom exeption, the scope of the outer listener function applies. Or in other words. If you have entered 4 times you have 4 mouseout listeners. And 3 of them can no longer find their child.

Without nesting removeChild works perfectly fine

```
    let posts = document.getElementById("post-alerts");

    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = "Inbox";

    posts.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
        this.parentElement.appendChild(p);
    })
    posts.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
        this.parentElement.removeChild(p);
    })
```